# Can a function return a 2d Array?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double matrixMultiply(double a[100][100],double b[100][100], int rowA,int colB,int colArowB){
    double c[100][100];
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<rowA;i++)
        for(j=0;j<colB;j++){
            for(k=0;k<colArowB;k++)
                c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]+b[k][j];}
    return c;
    }
int main()
{
    double a[100][100],b[100][100];
    int n,m,o,p,i,j;
    printf("%s \n", "Nr. linii A:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%s \n", "Nr. coloane A:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("%s \n", "Nr. linii B:");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    printf("%s \n", "Nr. coloane B:");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    printf("%s \n", "A=");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    printf("%s \n", "B=");
    for(i=0;i<o;i++)
        for(j=0;j<p;j++)
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    if(m==o){
    printf("Matricile se pot inmulti");
    cout<<matrixMultiply(a,b,n,m,p);
    return 0;}

    else printf("Matricile nu se pot inmulti");

    return 0;
}
```

I should multiply 2 matrices A & B, but I don't know how to return the matrix C, can somebody help?
There is an error returning the matrix C,also do I need a for to print the matrix C?

Comment: Since this is C++, why don't you just use something like a vector of vectors?

Comment: You can easily return a 2d array by returning a two dimensional `std::array` or `std::vector`. C-style arrays really are not worth the trouble.

Comment: You should either use C++ features and avoid C functions and headers or vice versa. Either use C with `printf` or C++ with `cout`.

Comment: This is really bad C++. I would say this is C, with the only exception of using `cout`.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise then I'd recommend using a template library like Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page. Not only will this make your life easier but it will also 
reduce inefficient temporary copies.

Answer (score 2):

> I should multiply 2 matrices A & B, but I don't know how to return the matrix C, can somebody help?

```
return c;
```

will not work since the array decays to a pointer. Not only that, the pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns since `c` is a function local variable.

If the size of the matrix is known at compile time, you may use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If the size of the matrix is known at run time only, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::vector`.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100> matrixMultiply(...) {}
```

or

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrixMultiply(...) {}
```

Comment: It should be noted that a vector of vectors is the same as a `T**` and can/will not be laid out in memory like a 2d array.

Comment: @NathanOliver `T**` *can* (and usually does in the case of matrices) point to an array with same memory layout like a 2d array. There is of course the extra array of `T*`, which point to the rows of `T` while with 2d array the location of rows is implicitly known from the type, but the rows of `T` that contain the values can have the same structure.

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated you could use the `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` but if you still want to use a 2D, array you need to dynamically allocate the 2D array in the function using a malloc and return a `double* matrixMultiply(double a[100][100],double b[100][100], int rowA,int colB,int colArowB)` or you could also allocate in the main function and just pass the address reference `cout<<matrixMultiply(&a,&b,n,m,p);`

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is not performance friendly and should be avoid for any serious code.

Answer (score -2):

`vector` maybe a better choice for this case in C++.

the function maybe looks like the following, and the entire program for this question is [here](https://github.com/nothingmi/stackoverflow-demo/tree/master/cpp-49654887)

```
using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> MatrixRow;
typedef vector<MatrixRow> Matrix;

Matrix matrix_multiply(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right)
{
    // Validate conditions of multiplication of matrices
    if (left.empty())
    {
        cerr << "Left matrix is empty." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (right.empty())
    {
        cerr << "Right matrix is empty." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    const int leftRowCount = left.size();
    const int leftColumnCount = left.front().size();

    const int rightRowCount = right.size();
    const int rightColumnCount = right.front().size();

    if (leftColumnCount != rightRowCount)
    {
        cerr << "The number of columns of the left matrix is not the same as the number of columns of the right matrix." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    cout << "Calculate steps" << endl
         << "=====" << endl;

    // Calculation
    Matrix matrix(leftRowCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < leftRowCount; i++)
    {
        matrix.at(i).resize(rightColumnCount);
        for (int j = 0; j < rightColumnCount; j++)
        {
            matrix.at(i).at(j) = 0;
            cout << "M(" << i << "," << j << ") = ";
            for (int k = 0; k < leftColumnCount; k++)
            {
                cout << "L(" << i << "," << k << ") + R(" << k << "," << j << ")";
                if (k < leftColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    cout << " + ";
                }
                matrix.at(i).at(j) += left.at(i).at(k) * right.at(k).at(j);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    return matrix;
}
```

More about identifier naming:

> #### In declarations
>
> An identifier can be used to name objects, references,
>   functions, enumerators, types, class members, namespaces, templates,
>   template specializations, parameter packs, goto labels, and other
>   entities, with the following exceptions:
>
> - the identifiers that are keywords cannot be used for other purposes;
> - the identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved; the
> - identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase
>     letter are reserved;
> - the identifiers that begin with an underscore are
>     reserved in the global namespace.

more about identifier naming in C++, visit [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) for details.

Comment: `_MatrixRow` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: @user2079303 this program works well, and what does your `reserved identifier` mean? could you show me some reference?

Comment: a reserved identifier is something that you mustn't define, or else the program will have undefined behaviour. For reference, see the section [reserved.names] of the standard. 'works well' is the second worst kind of UB.

Comment: @user2079303 thank you very much, I checked rules of the identifier naming. I will modify my code later!

Comment: @user2079303 the code has been updated, thanks for your help!